# How to check for a valid URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I am trying to write a function that will test for a valid URL I found this

```
 const pattern = new RegExp(
      '^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
        '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
        '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
        '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
        '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
        '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$',
      'i'
    ); // fragment locator
```

However it has a false positive it return `true` when I call it with `http://something` I need to check that url has a top level domain as well has a protocol `.org`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for completeness, `.org` is part of the domain.  The protocol is `http:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```js
const isValidUrl = (urlString) => {
    var urlPattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // validate protocol
        '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // validate domain name
        '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // validate OR ip (v4) address
        '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // validate port and path
        '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // validate query string
        '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // validate fragment locator
    return !!urlPattern.test(urlString);
}

const yourUrl = 'http://google.com';
const wrongUrl = 'http://google';
console.log(isValidUrl(yourUrl)); //true
console.log(isValidUrl(wrongUrl)); //false
```

Comment: No one actually does this, but it's also possible to specify an IP address as a single 32-bit integer.  20.81.111.85 can also be specified as `http://340881237` .

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isValidUrl(str) {
      const pattern = new RegExp(
        '^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
          '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
          '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
          '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
          '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
          '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', // fragment locator
        'i'
      );
      return pattern.test(str);
    }

    console.log(isValidUrl('https://stackoverflow.com')); // true
    console.log(isValidUrl('app://stackoverflow.com')); // false
    console.log(isValidUrl('stackoverflow')); // false
```

Answer (score -2):

- [URL Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
   const validateUrl = (arg) => {
try {
    new URL(arg);
} catch (e) {
    // throw new Error(e); (uncomment if debugging)
    return false;
}
return true;
}

console.log(validateUrl("https://google.com")); // true




const validateUrl = (arg) => {
    try {
        new URL(arg);
    } catch (e) {
        // throw new Error(e); (uncomment if debugging)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(validateUrl("https://google.com")); // true
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: if its not a valid url it will throw an error so wrap in try/catch

Comment: Then perhaps you should explain that.  An answer with one line of code and no explanation is not helpful.